# Split the array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i am getting the result in ajax console shows the array after that passing the  array value into php. But i want

```
1.cricket 
2.football
```

this type `php` page is not showing the this type of array value. I have tried also explode function not working.. please give me any idea..

```
 <?php
 $games=$_POST['id'];
 print_r($games);
 ?>
```

Php Page Result :

```
 Array ( [0] => Array (
                [id] => cricket 
                )
         [1] => Array ( 
                [id] => football
                ) 
       )
```

Comment: what you want `array` or `string`?? What does `1.cricket 2.football` mean?

Comment: Please define What is your output Requirement

Answer (score 6):

Now as you said you've tried `explode` function then its been used on string and not an array. What you can try over here is you can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) if `PHP version >= 5.5` like as

```
$required_array = array_column($your_array,'id');
```

or for lower version you can simply use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like as

```
$required_array = array_map('reset',$your_array);
```

Answer (score 4):

use: [array_column()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp)

```
$ids = array_column($games, 'id');
print_r($ids);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
  [0] => cricket
  [1] => football
)
```

> For simple string, just join or implode the final array. or if you need to do any format the browse the recent array and make your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with `foreach` without using any in built function.

```
<?php
$b = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 'cricket' ), 1 => array ( 'id' => 'football') );
$c = array();
if (! empty($b)) {
    foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
        $c[] = $v['id'];
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>'; // Get as an array.
$str = implode(', ', $c); // Get as a string.
echo '<pre>';print_r($str);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cricket
    [1] => football
)
cricket, football
```